# Mergesort code not working

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I am using C# to implement the code of mergesort();
Here is the code i wrote in main()

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = { 5,9,2,-10,53,-64,10,22,15,-60,2,3};
        Merge(arr,0,6,12);
    }
```

And here is the Merge() function

```
public static void Merge(int[] arr,int p,int q,int r ) 
    {
        int n1 = q-p;
        int n2 = r-q;
        int[] L=new int[n1];
        int[] R = new int[r-n2];
        for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
            L[i] = arr[i];
        foreach (int x in L)
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        for (int i = 0; i < r-n2; i++)
            R[i] = arr[q+i];
        Console.WriteLine("New part");
        foreach (int x in R)
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        int k=0, d=0;
        for (int i = p; i < r; i++)
        {
            if (L[k] <= R[k])
            {
                arr[i] = L[k];
                k++;
            }
            else
            {
                arr[i] = R[d];
                d++;
            }
        }
    }
```

The code is showing exception as index out of bound refering the line numbers containg int n1 = q-p; and Merge(arr,0,6,12);
Can anyone kindly help me

Comment: Don't post the same question twice. If you edit your code, do it in the original question.

Comment: I don't believe that is the line that is throwing the exception.

Comment: Asking two questions containing pretty much the same code / code throwing the same exception is usually a sign that you're doing something wrong in terms of how you use [so]. You definitely shouldn't update the code in the question as you go either (as this breaks the [so] model), but rather try to debug your program prior to asking, and, if you then end up still not having quite figured it out, try to phrase the question in such a way that an answer will tell you everything you need to know to figure it out from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Length of R[] = r - n2 = 12 - (12 - 6) = 6.

In the last for loop you iterate while i < r, i.e. i < 12. This means that you might try to get indexes 0 - 11 from R[] in the else-statement. This gives you an exception.

```
for (int i = p; i < r; i++)
    {
        if (L[k] <= R[k])
        {
            arr[i] = L[k];
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[i] = R[d];
            d++;
        }
    }
```

The exception fires from arr[i] = R[d].

Edit: Are you sure about your definition of the length of R[]?

```
int n2 = r - q;
...
int[] R = new int[r-n2]; // this is the same as int[] R = new int[q].
```